# How to start a screen and run a python script by command

Tags: bash

I'm working on a bash script which starts all my python scripts, I tried running this commands in a bash file

```
cd /home/project1 && screen -dmS project1 python3 project1.py
cd /home/project2 && screen -dmS project2 python3 project2.py
```

But this doesn't start the screen and doesn't run the commands, how can I make the scripts start after their screens started?

Comment: Aside: This is not a good way to do things. Back in Ye Olden Days the operating system didn't provide a good way to run a process in the background and retrieve its logs (or stop/start/restart) it at will, but we aren't in those days anymore. Modern operating systems provide process supervision systems like systemd, and you should use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally is to run those scripts using systemd as a service. First, create a file called `/usr/lib/systemd/system/project1.service` with the content bellow:

```
[Unit]
Description=Project1

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/project1.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save the file and run:

```
systemctl enable project1.service
systemctl start project1.service
```

The script should be running at this point, as a systemd service.

This is just a basic example. Systemd has a lot of configurations and functionalities and you can configure/adapt to suit your python script needs.

To see the status of the service you can issue this command: `systemctl status project1.service`

To see the service logs in real time you can do something like: `journalctl -fu project1.service`

Comment: Is there a way to see the logs of the python script? Also I have more than one or two scripts, I'm talking about 10-15 scripts running, is it good to add up to 15 services?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some additional details. And yes you can create a service for each of the scripts. If you would have chosen the screen route, then you would have had 10-15 screen sessions right? As for the logging, it depends if your python scripts logs anything...

Comment: Yes, I would have 10-15 screen sessions, so I assume it's better to have 10-15 services than having 10-15 screen sessions right? If it is, why?

Comment: That's how I would do it, using services instead of screen sessions